# IFTTT & Raspberry pi: Assigning value from terminal to IFTTT web request

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, ifttt

I made a Webhook Applet in IFTTT, which would send me a mail when "print" action triggers

In the URLs JSON body I can give values like this

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"9"}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/print/with/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

What I want to do is find my public ip address and pass it as value1.

I found my IP by

```
value1=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
echo $value1
```

How can I pass value1 to above URL

I tried

```
'{"value1":"$value1"}' 
'{"value1":{{$value1}}}' 
'{"value1":{{value1}}}'
```

P.S: I have zero basic knowledge in shell script. This is the first time i'm doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions inside single quotes do not get expanded in the shell, they are taken as literal. That means, if you store your IP address in a variable called `ip` like this:

```
ip=$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)
```

and you put that in single quotes, it won't get expanded:

```
echo '$ip'
$ip
```

whereas if you put it in double quotes, it will get expanded:

```
echo "$ip"
192.80.136.233
```

So, you need double quotes, but that will cause a problem because you need double quotes around your JSON strings, so you need to escape those by prefixing them with backslashes. So, you want:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"value1\":\"$ip\"}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already found that at the end of this [link](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aallan/bafc70a347f3b9526d30/raw/b9760af4b29fad0335c20a8a24607a52bba0cb6f/speedtest-ifttt.sh). Even though I didn't understande the code, I gave it a try and it worked. This is what it looks now `json="{\"value1\":\"${value1}\"}"`  <br/>`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "${json}"  https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/print/with/key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`